# React component rendered twice and useEffect not triggered

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using `React` + `Gatsby` and this is my first `React` project. I'm having some problems with a component which is called twice, and also the `useEffect` hook that I added to this component isn't triggered at all.

So far I have created a page called `CollectionsPage`:

```
import React from "react"
import { injectIntl } from "gatsby-plugin-intl"
import Layout from "../components/layout/layout"
import SEO from "../components/layout/seo"
import BGTState from "../context/bgt/bgtState"
import CollectionState from "../context/collection/collectionState"
import Collection from "../components/collection"

const CollectionsPage = ({ intl }) => {
  return (
    <BGTState>
      <Layout>
        <SEO
          lang={intl.locale}
          title={`${intl.formatMessage({ id: "collections" })}`}
        />
        {console.log("hey there")}
        <CollectionState>
          <Collection id={1} />
        </CollectionState>
      </Layout>
    </BGTState>
  )
}
export default injectIntl(CollectionsPage)
```

when I browse the site to `http://localhost:3001/collections` I get printed in the console:

```
hey there
true
true
```

now the first log `hey there` comes from the `CollectionsPage`, and the `true` logs are printed from the `Collection` component which is called twice.

This is my `Collection` component

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react"
import CollectionContext from "../context/collection/collectionContext"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const Collection = ({ id }) => {
  const collectionContext = useContext(CollectionContext)
  const { loading, collection, getCollection } = collectionContext

  console.log(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    getCollection(id)
  }, [])

  if (loading) return React.Fragment

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <img
          src={`${process.env.API_URL}${collection.feature_media.url}`}
          className="w-100 mt-2 mb-2"
          alt={""}
        />
        <Link to="#" className="bg-caption bg-no-underline">
          fall/winter 20/21
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Collection
```

now this behavior seems to happen only in the `CollectionsPage`, not in the `Index` page, and this is really confusing to me. This is the `Layout` component, which wrap everything on the page:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { injectIntl } from "gatsby-plugin-intl"
import BGTContext from "../../context/bgt/bgtContext"
import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap"
import Footer from "./footer"
import SearchState from "../../context/search/SearchState"
import Search from "../../components/search"

import NavbarMobile from "../../components/layout/navbarMobile"
import NavbarDesktop from "../../components/layout/navbarDesktop"

const Layout = ({ children, intl }) => {
  const bgtContext = useContext(BGTContext)
  const { loading, getSections, sections } = bgtContext

  useEffect(() => {
    getSections()
  }, [])

  return !loading ? (
    <>
      <NavbarMobile sections={sections} />
      <NavbarDesktop sections={sections} />
      <SearchState>
        <Search />
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="main">
            {children}
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </SearchState>
    </>
  ) : (
    <div className="container" style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
      <div className="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <Spinner animation="grow" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default injectIntl(Layout)
```

as you can see here, I have to get the sections from an API, and after this, I can render everything later. Maybe this mechanism is creating the problem?

Infact, in the `Collection` component I have another hook `useEffect` which call `getCollection`, the problem's that this hook is never triggered, and also the `collection` is undefine.

What can I do for fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all ,if you want your console.log to print once then inside the useEffect(present in Collections file) print your console.log.
And if you want to see if your `collection` value is getting changed or not do it like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(collections);
},[collections])
```

Whenever your collections value changes this useEffect will come into the picture.

Comment: if I use your code, so removing the `console.log` outside the `useEffect` and add it in `useEffect` nothing is printed out. I get `cannot read url of undefined`

Comment: I am asking you to move `console.log(true) ` inside  useEffect(() => {
console.log(true)
    getSections()
  }, [])

Comment: if I move `console.log(true)` in `useEffect(() => { console.log(true) getSections() }, [])`  is printed just one time

Comment: And if this `useEffect(()=>{
console.log(collections);
},[collections])` is giving you `cannot read url of undefined` then that means that whatever is providing the `collections` some value is not doing it correctly.

Comment: @sfarzoso yes exactly that is what i am saying ,that true will be printed just once if you do it the way i say it because that means only on the first render console.log will come into the picture or anything which is inside `useEffect(() => {
    // do whatever you want to
  }, [])`

Comment: Your Collections is being called just once,its just that you were not printing console.log correctly.

Comment: the `useEffect` inside the `Collection` component is not called, that's why `collection` is undefined. The API correctly return the response

Comment: if your api is correctly returning the response then try this `useEffect(()=>{ console.log(collectionContext); },[collectionContext])` if this isnt undefined then that means your api is returning response. And there is some issue with the way you are assigning `collections` some value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225861/discussion-between-sfarzoso-and-sakshi).